# joomla gantry footer-position is off

Tags: css, joomla, positioning

I am using Joomla 3 and Gantry framework to make a site. I just noticed that sometime during my fiddeling with the css för the site I have managed to mess up the positioning of the footer. It wont show at the bottom of the page anymore, it just sits fixed under the last module.

Can anyone give me a hint of what might be wrong?

the site is:
http://solstack.infinito.se/homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the offending style in gantry-custom.css:

```
div.rt-grid-6 {
    height: 166px;
}
```

It looks like you want this instead:

```
#rt-header div.rt-grid-6 {...
```

Generally it's a bad idea to override styles in such a general fashion. Put a class or ID on a particular element if you must force a size and style that instead, or look for an existing ID like I've done. I often use the module class suffix field for that purpose.

UPDATE:

Rather than forcing a height on a primary template element, you can fix what's inside it. Looks like you could use a div rather than a paragraph and accomplish the same thing without any styling. A div doesn't have bottom margin.

```
<div>
    <a title="Hem" target="_self" href="http://solstack.infinito.se/">
        <img alt="" src="/images/logotyp_400_trans.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks! And thanks for the advice. I actually thought that rt-grid6 was specifik for that module, but i see it wasnt. I'm still learning this.

Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. It's generally assumed that a class is likely to be used more than one time, which is why we include a parent ID. In the case of RT templates, a class is often only used once per parent ID element.